# Receive bluetooth data in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth

I am developing a windows application which has to continuously receive data from an android application (via Bluetooth). I searched the web and found that data can be sent from WPF app using '32feet.Net'.

How can I receive data via Bluetooth in WPF application?

Comment: You seem to have found the library to use for your needs. Have you read its [documentation](https://32feet.codeplex.com/documentation)?

Comment: @Otiel I saw the deocumentation. I just have to receive binary data (0 or 1) so for that even 8-bit data would be fine. For that which method should be used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634072/reading-raw-data-via-bluetooth..